# list assignment index out of range but range seems to work

Tags: python

I'm using OpenCV to read some pixels from several images and store the pixels in an array of which each index represents a single image, like this:

```
path = os.getcwd()
c = 0
for path in os.listdir(path + '\scribbles'):
    imgs[c] = cv2.imread(str(path),0)
    index[c] = np.where(imgs[c]!= [0])
    c = c + 1
```

All good here, now I want to create a list that has "N = number of images" as index, and for each index store all the X Coordinates, then do the same for the Y coordinates (on a separate list) like so:

```
path = os.getcwd()
c = 0
for path in os.listdir(path + '\scribbles'):
    xCoord[c] = list(index[c][0])
    yCoord[c] = list(index[c][1])
    c = c + 1

IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I can print to screen the set of coordinates for each index element, like so:

```
print(index[5][0])

[308 308 309 309 309 310 310 310 310 311 311 311 311 312 312 312 312 312
 312 313 313 313 313 313 313 313 313 314 314 314 314 314 314 314 314 315
 315 315 315 315 315 316 316 316 316 316 316 316 317 317 317 317 317 317
 317 317 318 318 318 318 318 318 318 318 318 318 318 318 319 319 319 319
 319 319 319 319 319 319 319 319 320 320 320 320 320 320 320 320 321 321
 321 321 321 321 321 321 322 322 322 322 322 322 322 322 322 323 323 323
 323 323 323 323 323 323 324 324 324 324 324 324 324 324 324 325 325 325
 325 325 325 325 325 325 326 326 326 326 326 326 326 326 327 327 327 327
 327 327 327 327 327 328 328 328 328 328 328 328 328 329 329 329 329 329
 329 329 329 329 330 330 330 330 330 330 330 330 330 331 331 331 331 331
 331 331 331 332 332 332 332 332 332 333 333 333 333 334 334 334 335 335
 335 336 372 372 372 372 372 373 373 373 373 373 373 374 374 374 374 374
 374 374 375 375 375 375 375 375 375 376 376 376 376 376 376 377 377 377
 377 378 378 378 378 379 379 379 379 379 379 380 380 380 380 380 381 381
 381 381 381 381 381 382 382 382 382 382 382 382 382 382 382 382 383 383
 383 383 383 383 384 384 385 385 385 386 386 387 388 389 390 391 392 392
 392 392 393 393 393 393 393 393 393 393 393 393 393 394 394 394 394 394
 394 394 394 394 394 395 395 395 395 395 395 395 395 395 395 396 396 396
 396 396 396 396 396 396 396 396 397 397 397 397 397 397 397 397 397 397
 398 398 398 398 398 398 398 398 398 398 399 399 399 399 399 399 399 399
 399 399 399 399 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 400 401 401
 401 401 401 401 401 401 401 401 401 401 402 402 402 402 402 402 402 402
 402 402 402 402 403 403 403 403 403 403 403 403 403 403 403 404 404 404
 404 404 404 404 404 404 404 405 405 405 405 405 405 405 405 405 406 406
 406 406 406 406 406 406 406 406 406 406 406 407 407 407 407 407 407 407
 407 407 407 407 407 407 407 408 408 408 408 408 408 408 408 408 408 408
 408 408 408 409 409 409 409 409 409 409 409 409 409 410 410 410 410 410
 410 410 410 410 411 411 411 411 411 411 412 412 412 412 412 413 413 413
 413 414 414 415 415 416 416 416 416 417 417 417 417 418 418 418 418 419
 419 419 419 420 420 420 420 421 421 421 421 421 422 422 422 422 423 423
 423 424 424 424 425 425 425 425 426 426 427 427 427 427 428 428 428 428
 429 429 429 429 429 430 430 430 430 430 431 431 432 432 433 433 433 433
 434 434 434 434 435 435 435 435 435 435 436 436 436 436 436 436 436 436
 437 437 437 437 437 437 437 437 438 438 438 438 438 438 438 439 439 439
 439]
```

and as expected, it fails if I use index 6 (i have 6 elements 0 to 5)

Can somebody help me figure out where the problem is?
Thank you

EDIT:
This is the code that ended up working for me

```
path = os.getcwd()
xCoord = []
yCoord = []

c = 0
for path in os.listdir(path + '\scribbles'):
    print(c)
    xCoord.append(list(index[c][0]))
    yCoord.append(list(index[c][1]))
    c = c + 1
```

Comment: How are `xCoord` and `yCoord` defined?  If they're just empty lists, then note that you cannot make a list longer by trying to assign to a nonexistent index - you have to use `.append()` instead.

Comment: Try printing the index c inside the loop to see which index is out of range.

Comment: Thank you @jasonharper this code is the one that ended up working for me path = os.getcwd()
xCoord = []
yCoord = []

c = 0
for path in os.listdir(path + '\scribbles'):
    print(c)
    xCoord.append(list(index[c][0]))
    yCoord.append(list(index[c][1]))
    c = c + 1

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**:

You need to append items to a list before you can access them using an index. Try

```
imgs = []
index = []

xCoord = []
yCoord = []

for path in os.listdir(path + '\scribbles'):
    img = cv2.imread(str(path),0)

    if img != [0]):
        x_coord = list(img[0])
        y_coord = list(img[1])

        xCoord.append(x_coord)
        yCoord.append(y_coord)
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked! Edit: actually for some reason it's copying the same set of values in all the 6 indices